# Spring MVC 3 exception : An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm getting na exception on the following method:

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody Account create(@Valid @RequestBody CreateAccountRequest request, BindingResult bindingResult)
{ ... 
}
```

Throws the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: An Errors/BindingResult argument is
>   expected to be immediately after the model attribute argument in the
>   controller method signature: public
>   com.mangofactory.concorde.domain.Account
>   com.mangofactory.concorde.api.AccountService.create(com.mangofactory.concorde.api.rpc.CreateAccountRequest,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)

According to the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), I'm required to add a `BindingResult` as the second parameter.  However, I've done that.

It's even present in the exception.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the way to solve this was to remove the `BindingResult` property completely.

The signature that worked was:

```
public @ResponseBody CreateAccountResponse create(@Valid @RequestBody CreateAccountRequest request)
```

This was as tipped by point #3 on [this blog post.](http://blog.goyello.com/2011/12/16/enhancements-spring-mvc31/)

Answer (score 3):

BindingResult is supported only after @ModelAttribute arguments. The combination of @Valid and @RequestBody raises a MethodArgumentNotValidException, which by default is translated to a 400 error code. This is documented in the reference documentation and on @RequestMapping itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `@RequestBody` in there, as your `CreateAccountRequest` class should already specify which parameters are bound to which types/vars (thus negating the need to use the HttpMessageConverters Spring provides).